# IE not accepting cookies on virtual machine

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies

I have a site that gets cookie info from a java servlet response and sets the cookies with javavascript.  The cookies are set and read properly on my local (Mac) machine in Chrome, FF, & Safari, and also on my virtual (Windows) machine in Chrome & FF.  BTW, The address I use on the virtual machine is my local IP address in this format:

```
http://192.168.40.22:8080/my/website
```

But when I use IE on this virtual machine, the cookies are not being accepted.  Any idea why not?

NOTE: on the virtual machine, i am able to accept cookies in IE from other sites and also on my website using a different browser.  The only issue happens when I'm using IE on my website.

EDIT: SOLVED! The virtual machine had an alternate default timezone.  I changed the timezone, and voila!  It worked!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: java? Or javascript? The two are different.

Comment: smells like JavaScript to me...

Comment: Thanks for providing how you solved your problem. What is the link between the VM timezone and the cookies? Is it a general issue? Was the servlet not sending a cookie because of the client's timezone?

Comment: The java servlet was sending the cookie, but the cookie had an expiration time of one hour.  The timezone on the virtual machine was two hours off of the server, so it was sending a cookie that was already expired.  What i still haven't figured out is why the other browsers weren't behaving the same way on the virtual machine.  I would've been able to solve this sooner if the other browsers had behaved the same way with the expired cookie.

Comment: Good question - I would guess that it is because IE has tighter integration with the OS than other browsers, and thus can detect such differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Internet Explorer settings. Control Panel > Internet Options.
Check the settings for the Security level where your site is.

Edit: also, if the machine has an Internet connexion, Google "are my cookies enabled" and see if it's a problem with every website or just yours.

Comment: I checked these settings, and they are all at the most open (least secure) settings I can have.  My cookies are enabled.  I am getting cookies from other sites on IE.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using a domain name instead of using the ip address. Configure the ip address to a host name in your hosts file and give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried this, but again, the cookies are not being set. :(

Comment: I just read your comment and I am glad you were able to figure it out. I am not sure how the timezone was affecting the cookies..